# smartsync offline-mode pagesize

Tags: mobile, smartstore, smartquery

I'm currently developing an hybrid app and I'm facing the following problem:

- On startup i need to load ALL the records from the cache (a soup). to do so I call fetch() on the Collection with the following query.

  ```
  {type:"cache", cacheQuery:{queryType:"smart", smartSql:"SELECT {tasks:_soup} FROM {tasks}", pageSize:100}}
  ```

Which retrieves up to 100 objects. Unfortunately I have more than 100 objects to load and if I increase the pagesize the query returns an error so I'm asking... Is there any way I can load more than pageSize record into the collection ( i need them all) .

TY in advance.

M.

Answer (score 3):

`pageSize` is actually an optional attribute so if you do not specify it, you should be getting everything at once. Also, you can use `hasMore()` and `getMore()` to check and retrieve subsequent records by keeping the existing page size value. The default `pageSize` value is 10